# How to make an edittext inside NestedScrollView have height = "parent"

Tags: android, kotlin

I want the Edittext to have a height equal to the full height of the NestedScrollView, but I don't know how to do it

```
        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/et_title"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_contain_rv"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/et_title"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="gone">

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/rv_checklist"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:visibility="visible"/>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/ll_add_checklist"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/_80sdp"
                    android:alpha="0.7">

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                        android:id="@+id/iv_add"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/_30sdp"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
                        android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp"
                        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                        app:tint="@color/black"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_add"/>

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_add"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
                        style="@style/AppTheme.TextView.Content_Note"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:text="@string/text_add_item"/>

                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <com.sophimp.are.RichEditText
                android:id="@+id/et_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:hint="@string/text_notes_here"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"
                style="@style/AppTheme.TextView.Content_Note"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="4dp"
                android:visibility="visible"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

This is an image of the NestedScrollView's scope[enter image description here][1]

This is an image of the scope of Edittext[enter image description here][2]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ca674.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TG3N.png

I want the Edittext to take up the remaining height of the NestedScrollView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way, just in NestedScrollView set "android:fillViewport="true"" and in Edittext set " android:layout_height="match_parent""

Answer (score 0):

I have almost same issue in my code, I have Used Relative Layout for the solution. Here is code with I have used.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    
     <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/et_title"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">
      <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
    
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/ll_contain_rv"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/et_title"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:visibility="gone">
    
                    <!-- Your RecyclerView and other views here -->
    
                </LinearLayout>
    
                <com.sophimp.are.RichEditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" <!-- Set the height to match_parent-->
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    android:hint="@string/text_notes_here"
                    android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"
                    style="@style/AppTheme.TextView.Content_Note"
                    android:gravity="top"
                    android:lineSpacingExtra="4dp"
                    android:visibility="visible"/>
    
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
    
    </RelativeLayout>
```

try above may it helpful to you.

Comment: I tried it and didn't see any change